# json-server --watch db.json in error TypeError: lodash.runInContext is not a function

Tags: json-server

C:\Documents\Project>json-server --watch db.json

{^_^}/ hi!

Loading db.json
TypeError: lodash.runInContext is not a function
at module.exports (C:\Users\Taras Kundyk\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\json-server\node_modules\lowdb\lib\main.js:12:18)
at C:\Users\Taras Kundyk\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\json-server\lib\cli\utils\load.js:45:15
at new Promise ()
at module.exports (C:\Users\Taras Kundyk\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\json-server\lib\cli\utils\load.js:36:10)
at start (C:\Users\Taras Kundyk\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\json-server\lib\cli\run.js:112:12)
at module.exports (C:\Users\Taras Kundyk\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\json-server\lib\cli\run.js:149:3)
at module.exports (C:\Users\Taras Kundyk\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\json-server\lib\cli\index.js:86:3)
at Object. (C:\Users\Taras Kundyk\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\json-server\lib\cli\bin.js:6:14)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)

I can't run the server.

I've already tried to install (and reinstall) json-server global and locally npm install -g json-server and npm install json-server and then run json-server --watch db.json, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

That's an [issue with `lodash@4.17.16`](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/4845).
It was solved in newer versions, so you can update using `npm install lodash@^4.17.19`

Answer (score -1):

```
npm install json-server@0.17.4
npx json-server --watch db.json
```